# PDO insert information from one database to another

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, fetch

Im trying to insert information from one database table to another but it doesnt seem to be working.

Here is my approve.php file =

```
<?php
if($_POST['approve']) {
$mysql = "INSERT INTO approved_videos WHERE id = " . $info['id'] . " SET `title` = '" . $info['title'] . "', `description` = '" . $info['description'] . "', `name` = '" . $info['name'] . "', `email` = '" . $info['email'] . "', `country` = '" . $info['country'] . "', `videotmp` = '" . $info['videotmp'] . "', `videotype` = '" . $info['videotype'] . "', `videosize` = " . $info['videosize'] . ", `videopath` = '" . $info['videopath'] . "'";
$dbh->exec($mysql) or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));
}
?>
```

And here is the page that display the information with the approve or decline button which approved is clicked the information will be transfered from one database table to another =

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="homelink.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="logoutlink.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="right-content">
<?php
$dir = dirname("connection/directory");
require($dir . 'thisismyconnectionfile.php');

$dbh = pdo_videos();

$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM videos");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while ($info = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<table width=\"100%\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    $coverid = $info['id']; 
    echo "<td>" . $info['title'] . "</td>";

    $smalldesc = substr($info['description'], 0, 50) . "...";

    echo "<td>" . $smalldesc . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $info['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $info['country'] . "</td>";

    include("process/approve.php");

    echo "<td width='100px'><form action='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'><input type='submit' name='approve' value='Approve' /></form></td>";
    echo "<td width='100px'><form action='process/decline.php' method='post'><input type='submit' name='decline' value='Decline' /></form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>   
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know where im going wrong?

**EDIT**

I have changed my query to the following -

```
"INSERT INTO approved_videos(title,desc,name,email,country,videotmp,videotype,videosize,videopath) SELECT videos.title,videos.desc,videos.name,videos.email,videos.country,videos.videotmp,videos.videotype,videos.videosize,videos.videopath FROM videos WHERE id = videos.id";
```

And in the error log i get the following error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,name,email,country,videotmp,videotype,videosize,videopath) SELECT videos.ti' at line 1' in /bla/bla/bla/process/approve.php:4
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATED EDIT**

Ok so i was reading the mysql website looking around and playing about with my code a little and ive edited my query to the following -

```
$mysql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO approved_videos(approved_videos.title,approved_videos.desc,approved_videos.name,approved_videos.email,approved_videos.country,approved_videos.videotmp,approved_videos.videotype,approved_videos.videosize,approved_videos.videopath) SELECT videos.title,videos.desc,videos.name,videos.email,videos.country,videos.videotmp,videos.videotype,videos.videosize,videos.videopath FROM videos WHERE videos.id = :id");
```

It runs that query and i get no errors however it doesnt actually insert the information from videos table to approved_videos table so have i missed something?

**FIXED**

Ok so after playing around a bit more instead of including it i just executed it from the approve.php file however in the action i put

```
'process/approve.php?id='" . $info['id'] . ">
```

and the in my approve.php file where i have the query i changed id to -

```
videos.id = :id
```

But also added -

```
$mysql->bindParam(":id" ,$_GET['id']);
```

Which fixed my issue.

Comment: [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) doesn't have a `WHERE` clause, [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) does. Plus, where/how is `$info` being populated from?

Comment: I just updated the code as i realised that i hadnt included the file, so how can i insert one specific row of information from a table to another one

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html - INSERT SELECT however does support a `WHERE` clause; that is what you most likely need to use.

Comment: Am i on the right lines - `$mysql = "INSERT approved_videos(title, description,name,email,country,videotmp,videotype,videosize,videopath) SELECT videos.title,videos.description,videos.name,videos.email,videos.country,videos.videotmp,videos.videotype,videos.videosize,videos.videopath FROM videos WHERE id = videos.id";`

Comment: You forgot the word "into" for `INSERT approved_videos` - `INSERT INTO approved_videos`. Try it out after and see what you get.

Comment: I added the `INTO` but it still doesnt insert the information from the videos table into the approve_videos table

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is wrong, try something like this:

```
$mysql = "INSERT INTO approved_videos SELECT * FROM videos where id = ".$info['id'];
```

Comment: No that doesnt seem to work either but thanks anyway

Comment: Looking at the error log it has logged this - `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /bla/bla/bla/process/approve.php:4`

Comment: Change the query up to the fields of your table but without the auto incr. prim key. ex.: `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE id=:id`

Comment: Both tables has the same structure? Remove the primary key field from appoved_videos and try again.

Comment: ive changed it to :id and still no luck, i get the error message in my EDIT section

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to insert a record with the same key in the table, id you edit your table removing the primary key you can insert the record. Does both tables have the same fields?

Comment: Yes both tables have the same fields but i have managed to fix it now but thanks anyway